# Core data to save UItableview and edited changes in it

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I am new to iPhone programming..I am trying an app with a tableview which has profile name and images of people..the tableview is editable and adding new name and picture, deleting an existing one and rearranging the table are possible..the tableview and changes to it should be saved using core data..I have completed everything except the core data part..dont know how to go about doing that part..
Can anyone help with how to start and how to proceed?..are there any examples or sample codes which I can try out and learn, in which core data is used for saving and loading tableviews..I am using Xcode 4.3.2..

I went through the tutorials links that i got in the initial answers..but I am still having trouble..Still at a loss as to where I should start..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started to learn Core Data with this simple tutorial:

[Core Data on iOS 5 Tutorial: Getting Started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started)

[Core Data on iOS 5 Tutorial: How To Use NSFetchedResultsController](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller)

Comment: went through those tutorials..but still can't understand how I can save changes to the tableview that I already made..

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you start with *Stanford CS193P: iPad and iPhone App Development (Fall 2011)* on *iTunes U*. You can also take a look at Core Data related WWDC 2011 and WWDC 2012 sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has short and easy Core Data example here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html

Once you gone through that, you can try manually inserting the Core Data code into your application since you've already started your project but for new project, I recommend using one of Apple's templates that contain Core Data. Makes it easier.

Comment: Since I knew that core data has to be implemented, I did this much in empty project template with 'use core data' selected..I was hoping that it would be of some use..